# Android: Alternative for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to display an overlay across app activities

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I would like to add a chat feature in my app that would be available across all activities - you can start a chat within one activity and keep it live when changing activities.

Before Android M (6.0 - API 23), I was able to add the following permission in the app manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

And create a view above all others using `TYPE_PHONE` LayoutParam.

Since Marshmallow, I am now required to ask for user permission using the following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
    }
}
```

My problem is, this is very intrusive for users, plus I don't need a view visible over all applications - a view visible over my app would be enough.

Does such a solution exist?
One other constraint I have is that I can't always modify the app layout files - my chat feature could be included inside other apps.

Thank you.

Comment: "Does such a solution exist?" -- rewrite your app to have only one activity. Otherwise, I am not aware of any solution.

Comment: @Damien were you able to solve it?